# How to manipulate XML data trough Java scripting API

Tags: java, xml

I am writing something that may be called workflow engine. For that I have created data model for the workflow as XML following specific XML Schema.

Below is an example of XML representing this data model:

```
<dm:agentModel xmlns:dm="ProcessObjects" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="ProcessObjects agentModel.xsd">
    <dm:cfp isList="false" objName="myCFP"></dm:cfp>
    <dm:proposal isList="true" objName="receivedProposals"></dm:proposal>
    <dm:feedbackList objName="cfpFeedbacks">
      <dm:item>
        <dm:to>Andrew</dm:to>
        <dm:from>Paul</dm:from>
        <dm:heading>That is bad</dm:heading>
        <dm:body>Fix points a, b and c, please.</dm:body>
      </dm:item>  
      <dm:item>
        <dm:to>Frank</dm:to>
        <dm:from>Paul</dm:from>
        <dm:heading>Very good!</dm:heading>
        <dm:body>I see no drawbacks. You can also ask Matthew for additional feedback.</dm:body>
      </dm:item>  
    </dm:feedbackList>
</dm:agentModel>
```

The workflow definition, which is defined by the user by the means of web editor is the BPMN XML standard. For not going too deep in the details, i need to give user possibility to define some scripting interface. User needs to be able to writhe something like:

```
/*JavaScript code*/
for(var i=0; i<agentModel.cfpFeedbacks.length; i++) {
    if(agentModel.cfpFeedbacks[i].to == "Frank") {
        agentModel.cfpFeedbacks[i].to += " Sinatra";
    }
}
```

By now, I wrote Java class (`DataModel`) that can access data built from XML given above. Because XML may contain many different objects, there are getters and setters that looks like:

```
/*Java code*/
DataModel agentModel = new DataModel(xmlString);
agentModel.getValue("cfpFeedbacks[1].to");
//returns String "Frank"
agentModel.setValue("cfpFeedbacks[0].from", "Paul Anka");
//obvious
```

To run user-written script I am trying to use Java Scripting API

```
/*Java code*/
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

//binding object 
engine.put("agentModel", agentModel);
String script =   "var i = 0;"
                + "println(agentModel.getValue(\"cfpFeedbacks[\" + i + \"].from\"));";
engine.eval(script);
```

Which is more or less working. What I want to archieve is something like this working:

```
/*Java code*/
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

//binding object 
engine.put("agentModel", agentModel);
String script =   "var i = 0;"
                + "println(agentModel.cfpFeedbacks[i].from);";
/**
* any magic operations here
*/
engine.eval(script);
```

Goal is to provide easiest-possible interface for end users to write their scripts.

I am a little bit lost and I would be grateful for any inspiration. Personally I did consider three scenarios:

- Creating Java-Bean style classes, and compiling them instead of working on XML
- Parsing script string from second to the first form (which seems to be most easy, but time expensive and definitely not 'clean')
- Developing some kind of magic interface to the object where calling `object.field` is synonym for calling `object.getValue("field")`

Maybe there is some obvious workaround I don't see.

Thanks in advance for any replies,

PS. If my description is unclear, or you find it is worth to provide more source code I'll clarify question immidiately. Getting it done is right now priority for me.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is deserialize xml to java object and then just put result into engine.

You are able to direct operate on objects putted via `engine.put(..)` method

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
engine.put("a", 1);
engine.put("b", 5);
engine.eval("a = 2;");
Object result = engine.eval("c = a + b;");
System.out.println("a + b = " + result);
```

Finally get object from script engine and serialize object to xml, [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml)  will be useful